# Fetch Meta data of external url using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata

I have a requirement to fetch Image(meta image) from an external url like 
https://www.amazon.in/Bangalore-Refinery-Lakshmi-Yellow-Pendant/dp/B084LFLYCT/ref=sr_1_10?tag=coupondesam-21
and display its image on my angular SPA (Using angular 9)

If we post this image on whatsapp it will fetch meta data like image title and displays in chat or group, in the similar terms I want to fetch the meta data and use it in my website to display users.